# Как из программы на Python 3 дергать функции из WinAPI

Tags: python, winapi

Собственно вопрос в следующем. Как из программы на `Python 3` дергать функции из `WinAPI`. Для `Python 2.4` + есть [`PyWin32`](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/), для 3.x же ничего подобного найти не могу. Ну или, может быть, кто-то сможет подсказать как без использования `WinAPI` в `Python` вызвать функцию, если известен её адрес в памяти.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте pywin32
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Comment: Спасибо, вроде бы как раз то, что нужно

Comment: Только сейчас до меня как до жирафа дошел прикол, что автор в вопросе говорил про этот модуль, а я ему про него же говорю.  
Единственно автор не знал, что есть версия и для 3.3